# When I install on USB stick, will it replace Windows 7?

Tags: windows, usb

I want Ubuntu really bad on my USB stick but I am afraid to install it, because I wonder if it will replace Windows.

Comment: Make sure to **only** install on the USB in case you are worried: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to either replace windows 7 with ubuntu or **Install ubuntu along side windows 7**.

Here is a step by step guide to do it manually

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/10/dual-booting-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/

To let ubuntu do everything to get it installed alongside windows 7. Don't resize your C: drive, and choose `Install ubuntu alongside windows 7` in `Installation type` window

Comment: OP seems to want to install **on** a USB stick not **from** a USB stick. At least that's how the question reads.

Answer (score 0):

If you disable your internal HDD prior to installing Ubuntu to the USB, you will be 100% sure of not breaking Windows.